# How do I set the Provider Value from inside the Scaffold in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I would like to set the value of the `Provider` from inside the `Scaffold`. But I'm not sure how I can do that.

Listed below is the code within which I would like to set the value of the `Provider`.

```
return Scaffold(
            body: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 2.5.h),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.w),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      " $categoryName Courses",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 10.sp,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 1.h),
                Expanded(
                  child: CoursePage(
                    courseList: ListCategoryCourses(listScrollDirection: Axis.vertical, categoryName: categoryName),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
```

I would like to set the `Provider` value once the `Column` has been executed or on the `dispose` method getting executed.

But the `dispose` method isn't getting executed, how can I force the `dispose` method to get executed?

Listed below is the code to set the `Provider` value:

```
              Provider.of<CategoryProvider>(context, listen: false).currentCategoryDetails(
                currentCategorySelected: false,
                currentCategoryName: null,
              );
```

Answer (score -1):

try to make object in build method

```
var obj = Provider.of<CategoryProvider>(context, listen: false).currentCategoryDetails(
            currentCategorySelected: false,
            currentCategoryName: null,
          );
```

this obj use where ever you want in scaffold or in build method

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm getting the following compile time error ```This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.  Try checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void.```